# Detecting beginning of line and end of line in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$data = $_POST['data'];

echo '<form method="post"><textarea name="data"></textarea><input type="submit">';

echo preg_replace( "#/*[?+]/n#", "[h1]$1[/h1]",$str );
```

Is it possible with `preg_replace` to detect the beginning of a line and apply a certain html code to the entire line based on a few characters at the beginning of it?

Here, based on the * if the data were:

```
*This is row one
//output <h1>This is row one</h1>

**This is row two
//output <h2>This is row two</h2>

***This is row three
//output <h3>This is row three</h3>

***This is row * three
//output <h3>This is row * three</h3>

This is row * three
//output This is row * three
```

I'm having troble detecting the begining of the line and end of the line and wrapping tags around the text in the line.

I don't need any `*` in between the line matched. My failed effors are included. Can you help?

Comment: Are you trying to build a Markdown interpreter?

Comment: Just 4 things. Don't think you can call it a MarkDown interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html for full details

```
// replace *** with h3
$str = preg_replace('/^\*{3}([^\*].*)$/', '<h3>$1</h3>', $str);

// replace ** with h2
$str = preg_replace('/^\*{2}([^\*].*)$/', '<h2>$1</h2>', $str);

// replace * with h1
$str = preg_replace('/^\*([^\*].*)$/', '<h1>$1</h1>', $str);
```

Explanation: `*` is a special character in regular expressions, so it has to be escaped, like so: `\*`.

`^\*` searches for `*` at the beginning of the string. `[^\*]` searches for anything that is NOT `*` -- the square brackets are used to search for a class of characters, and the `^` means 'NOT'. Therefore, to search for `***` without also matching `****`, we use the expression `/^\*{3}[^\*]/`.

Comment: In your solution, can you get them to check for 1, 2 and 3 `*`s. Problem with them is, if I use a single one and enter `**Cat` I get `<h1>*Cat</h1>. I did add a `{1}, but that did not help. Any help?

Comment: `****Hello` results in `<h3>*Hello</h3>. Nothing should happen to it.

Comment: Corrected that. Are there any other rules that need to be accounted for?

Comment: ****Hello print ****Hello. No changes or processing needed. Only `*` and `**` and `***` need to be checked and processed.

Answer (score 1):

#### Code:

```
$str = "*This is row one\n**This is row two\n***This is row three\n***This is row * three\nThis is row * three"; 
 
$result = preg_replace('/^\*([^*].*)$/m', '<h1>$1</h1>', $str);

$result = preg_replace('/^\*{2}([^*].*)$/m', '<h2>$1</h2>', $str);

$result = preg_replace('/^\*{3}([^*].*)$/m', '<h2>$1</h2>', $str);
```

Comment: If there one `*` it's`H1`. If there's `**` its `H2`. Even if i do `*Test` and `**Test 2` from a text box, it's always `H1`

Comment: Ok then it cannot be done in single `preg_replace`. Let me edit.

Comment: This works nice. But if its `****` it does `<H3>*TExt</h3>` It should igrone that print it as it is. Only lines with `*` and `**` and `***` need to be checked and processed.

Comment: Ah ok, it wasn't clear if that needed to be ignored. It is fixed now.

Comment: But now I can see `([^*].*)` trick leaking over to other answer :)